# MySQL Syntax Error; Works in PHPMyAdmin but not in PHP Code

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure out why this isn't working when it is ran in my PHP script. It works fine using PHPMyAdmin...

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'INSERT INTO `gamecoms_website`.`DailyUsers` (UserCount, TheDate, TheTime, TheDat' at line 2
```

Here is the code:

```
SET SESSION time_zone = '+00:00';
    INSERT INTO `gamecoms_site`.`DailyUsers` (UserCount, TheDate, TheTime, TheDateTime) VALUES ('$online', CURDATE(), CURTIME(), NOW());
    DELETE FROM `gamecoms_site`.`DailyUsers` WHERE TheDateTime < ADDTIME(NOW(), '-24:00:00');
    SELECT `UserCount`, `TheDate` , `TheTime`, `TheDateTime` INTO @UserCount ,@TheDate ,@TheTime ,@TheDateTime FROM `gamecoms_website`.`DailyUsers` ORDER BY UserCount DESC LIMIT 1;
    UPDATE  `gamecoms_site`.`AllTimeUsers`
        SET
            TheDate = CASE WHEN UserCount < @UserCount THEN @TheDate END,
            TheTime = CASE WHEN UserCount < @UserCount THEN @TheTime END,
            TheDateTime = CASE WHEN UserCount < @UserCount THEN @TheDateTime END,
            UserCount = CASE WHEN UserCount < @UserCount THEN @UserCount END;
```

Comment: Post your PHP code over here

Comment: remove ` from SQL. it will work

Comment: I don't know your `PHP` code but you have to call [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) instead of [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to execute more than one query at once.

Comment: You are not showing the correct code. error message shows a different DB name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.multi-query.php

Or separate queries

Comment: I was unaware mysqli_multi_query was a thing. It worked. Thanks!